# English International is not an option in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

I work in English and Spanish languages and want to change from one to another quickly as I was able to do with International English, However I am not able to change my keyboard to International English in my new computer because is not an option for windows 10.

Comment: It is an option but you need to add the additional keyboard layout.

Answer (score 3):

This area has changed in Windows 10.
In the recent terminology, you are looking for the International keyboard layout
of the English language:

- Start *Settings*
- Go to *Time & Language > Language*
- Under Preferred languages, click on *English*
  (you will need to add it, if not already there)
- Click on *Options*
- Under Keyboards, click on *+ Add a keyboard*
- Choose your keyboard layout, for example "United States-International".

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that that the "United States-International" keyboard layout is now "Interlingua". Thank you Windows 10 for sending us polyglots out on a wild goose chase.
I am yet to know how stable this setting is, since for the past month it was jumping between English (US) and Spanish (US) (the very distant second best I could find to write accents), adding insult to injury.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).